# How to see when browser tab is loaded webbrowser modle Python

Tags: python, window

So essentially I am using the webbrowser module in python. I want to see when a browser tab is loaded in the default browser for Windows. Essentially I need to click and type stuff after the page loads. I need to be as efficient as possible with my app, hence I cannot use wait states. Thanks!

Comment: you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser.

Comment: I get that but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: find some tutorial. At start see documentation in previous link - ie. [Getting Started](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html). And install [Driver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers) for your browser.